# In search for pythonic elegance: dictionary instead a repetitive spaghetti block

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists

I have a script which transforms a nested list into LaTeX formatted table. The tricky part is related with cells colored by their values. Let's say that I have a nested list like this:

[[0.40, -0.13, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00], [-1.90, -0.56, -0.57, -0.66, -1.37], [4.07, 0.24, 2.56, 0.02, 0.02], [6.43, 0.23, 0.33, 0.18, 0.02], [11.80, 4.81, 4.86, 3.96, 6.03], [4.05, 1.94, 0.09, 0.01, 0.03]]

that part of my script goes like this

```
for fila in listainicial:
#seudocódigo
    mes1 = ""
    mes2 = ""
    mes3 = ""
    mes4 = ""
    mes5 = ""
if float(fila[0]) >= 100:
        mes1 = "\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{100pc}"
    elif float(fila[0]) > 30:
        mes1 = "\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{masde30pc}"
    elif float(fila[0]) > 20:
        mes1 = "\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{20to30pc}"
    elif float(fila[0]) > 10:
        mes1 = "\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{10to20pc}"
    elif float(fila[0]) > 5:
        mes1 = "\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{5to10pc}"
    elif float(fila[0]) > 0:
        mes1 = "\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{0to5pc}"
    elif float(fila[0]) == 0:
        mes1 = "\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{0pc}"
    elif float(fila[0]) > -5:
        mes1 = "\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{m5to0pc}"
    elif float(fila[0]) > -10:
        mes1 = "\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{m10tom5pc}"
    elif float(fila[0]) > -25:
        mes1 = "\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{m25tom10pc}"
    elif float(fila[0]) <= -25:
        mes1 = "\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{menosdem25pc}\\color{white}"
```

the code repeats for fila[1] to fila[4]

this is so unpythonic that I feel dirty, sort of. My script works and copypaste blocks is not a problem but, as I point out in the title, I want to produce a more elegant and satisfying code.

I really would like to substitute such long and monotonous series of if...elif with a dictionary. I also would appreciate any other solution which reduces my 110-line long part of the script.

I would really appreciate any hint or solution in this sense

Thanks in advance

Comment: Put it inside a function and call it 5 times in a loop.

Comment: every common part can be abstracted out. The "\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{ }"
The mes1 =  and the eonditions themselves, if they are the same for each variable. You can also find an hashing algoritem which will match the input value (fila[x]) with the right dynamic value ("100pc","masde30pc" ... "menosdem25pc}\\color{white"

Comment: Sorry, all the strings inside \\cellcolor are just LaTeX defined colours. I didn't explained it

Answer (score 2):

Here is my attempt at encapsulating your code and making it a little bit less ungainly:

Everything above `if name == main` can be extracted in a separate module, making your main code look like this:

```
boundaries = [float('-inf'), -25, -10, -5, 0 - EPSILON, 0 + EPSILON, 5, 10, 20, 30, 100, float('inf')]
listainicial = [the values you have]
latex_string_values =  get_latex_values(listainicial, boundaries)
```

I added docstrings to explain what each class/method does; please let me know if something needs more explaining.

```
from typing import NamedTuple, List


EPSILON = 1e-8


class Interval(NamedTuple):
    """represents an interval on the number line, where the high value is included
    """
    low : float
    high : float

    def contains(self, value: float)-> bool:
        return self.low < value <= self.high


class Intervals:
    """represents a collection of Interval on the number line
    """
    def __init__(self, boundaries: List[float]):
        self.intervals = [Interval(low=low, high=high)
                          for low, high in zip(boundaries[:-1], boundaries[1:])]

    def get_interval(self, value: float)-> Interval:
        """returns the interval the value belongs to
        """
        for interval in self.intervals:
            if interval.contains(value):
                return interval
        raise ValueError('this value does not belong here')

    def __iter__(self):
        for interval in self.intervals:
            yield interval


class LatexValues:
    """a class that parses and assigns latex strings based on whether a value
    is contained in an interval
    """
    latex_values = ["\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{menosdem25pc}\\color{white}",
                    "\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{m25tom10pc}",
                    "\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{m10tom5pc}",
                    "\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{m5to0pc}",
                    "\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{0pc}",
                    "\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{0to5pc}",
                    "\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{5to10pc}",
                    "\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{10to20pc}",
                    "\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{20to30pc}",
                    "\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{masde30pc}",
                    "\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{100pc}"
                    ]

    def __init__(self, boundaries: List[List[float]]):

        self.boundaries = boundaries[:]
        self.intervals = Intervals(boundaries)
        self.assigned_values = {interval: latex_value for interval, latex_value
                                in zip(self.intervals, LatexValues.latex_values)}

    def get_latex(self, value: float)-> str:
        return self.assigned_values[self.intervals.get_interval(value)]


def get_latex_values(listainicial: List[List[float]], boundaries: List[float])-> List[List[str]]:
    """
    :param listainicial: a data structure that contains the values used to assign Latex strings
    :param boundaries: the boundaries of the intervals segregating the values
    :return: the appropriate latex string corresponding to a value
             a list of lists that contain the latex_values for mes1-mes5 for each fila in filainicial
    """

    latex_values = LatexValues(boundaries)
    results = []
    for fila in listainicial:
        result = []
        for mes in range(5):
            result.append(latex_values.get_latex(fila[mes]))
        results.append(result)
    return results


if __name__ == '__main__':

    boundaries = [float('-inf'), -25, -10, -5, 0 - EPSILON, 0 + EPSILON, 5, 10, 20, 30, 100, float('inf')]
    test_listainicial = [[0, 22, 43, -200, 1], [12, -4, -12, 110, 41]]
    for result in get_latex_values(test_listainicial, boundaries):
        print(result)
```

#### output:

```
['\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{0pc}', '\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{20to30pc}', '\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{masde30pc}', '\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{menosdem25pc}\\color{white}', '\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{0to5pc}']
['\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{10to20pc}', '\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{m5to0pc}', '\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{m25tom10pc}', '\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{100pc}', '\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{masde30pc}']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a sorted list of tuples of (limit, color):

```
colors = [(-25,'menosdem25pc'), (-10, 'm25tom10pc'), (-5, 'm10tom5pc')...]
```

Then, you can filter search for the interesting one:

```
list_of_bigger_tuples = [x for x in colors where x[0]>fila[0]]
first_tuple = list_of_bigger_tuples[0]
color = first_tuple[1]
```

and now you can compose the string:

```
result = "\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{" + color + "}"
```

This is not exactly what you are doing: for values <=25 I'm missing part of the string, and I'm assuming all comparators are `>`. But you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks you people for the answers, quite enlightening and inspiring for other issues that I have. However, I wanted to use dictionaries and to iterate through variable names, so I finally started with @Poshi answer and ended with this

```
for fila in listainicial:
    ISI = ""
    mes1 = ""
    mes2 = ""
    mes3 = ""
    mes4 = ""
    mes5 = ""
    dictiocell = {"%s >= 100":"100pc", "100 > %s > 30":"masde30pc", "30 >= %s > 20":"20to30pc", "20 >= %s > 10":"10to20pc", "10 >= %s > 5":"5to10pc", "5 >= %s > 0":"0to5pc", "%s == 0":"0pc", "0 > %s > -5":"m5to0pc", "-5 >= %s > -10":"m10tom5pc", "-10 >= %s > -25":"m25tom10pc"}
    for n in range (1,6):
        for p in dictiocell:
            if eval(p %float(fila[n+2])):
                globals()["mes%s" % n] = "\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{" + dictiocell[p] + "}" 
        if float(fila[n+2]) <= -25:
            globals()["mes%s" % n] = "\\footnotesize{}\\cellcolor{menosdem25pc}\\color{white}"
```

As it works, I post it because it can be helpful to other people here.

Thanks again. @reblochon, your example is inspiring of all that I need to learn and improve in python